# Chaining Together PAW Requests

Tags: paw-app

Is there any way to chain together a series of defined PAW Requests?  For example I POST to an end point and parse the response to get an ID from a newly created resource to then turn around and trigger a GET for that resource using that parsed ID value.  Assuming the response is in JSON, but doesn't really matter, just looking to see is that is possible via a hook/extension or other ways?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. There is no way for now to actually chain the requests, but if you hit Request > Send All (⌥⌘⏎) all requests will be sent sequentially. Or select the requests you want and Send. They will be sent in the order they appear in the list. Though, it's not possible via a hook or extension for now, sorry. That's a nice suggestion, thought! Thanks.